# How to manage bookmarks from XSL-FO after merging multiple PDF using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, xslt, pdfbox, apache-fop

I have written an XSL-FO file as a template for generating a PDF containing 3 bookmarks, each one of them pointing to a different PDF.

The thing is, I generate the 3 pdf and then I merge them together using PDFBox.
At the time of generation, the first PDF doesn't know about the other 2 so the merged PDF bookmark links don't work.

Should I rethink how I managed my bookmarks (inside XSL-FO) and use PDFBox tools instead? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: If don't think merging pdf files containing broken bookmarks can lead to having working bookmarks. On the other hand, if each pdf contains working bookmarks, the merged pdf should have working bookmarks too.

Comment: Each PDF contains 1 working bookmark (referencing themselves) and 2 not working because it's not existing yet

Comment: Just to clarify, are we talking of _bookmarks_ (usually shown in a side panel by the pdf reader) or _links_ (a piece of content pointing to a different piece of content)? Because having 3 bookmarks in each file (regardless of their working or not) would make the merged file have 9. If in the final file you need a bookmark for each original file, you could try merging files each having a single bookmark to their (first, or relevant) page.

Comment: I'm talking about both as on the first page of the merged PDF, I have 3 links corresponding to the 3 bookmarks that are also shown in the side panel. I didn't think about doing what you suggested, i'll try it out

Comment: So I've tested it and it works just fine for the bookmarks, but what about the links? I'm guessing there is no way to make them work before the generation, so I should use PDFBox to add it afterwards?

Comment: internal links in a PDF must reference a page object, not a page number. So you can't set links in advance. See the AddAnnotations.java example from the source code download for how to set a link (this may also help on how to change one).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test adding annotations because my version of PDFBox (1.8.16) does not contains the PDDocument.getPage() method, so I can't link my annotation to a PDPage.
I can't upgrade my PDFBox version either as our project is using JDK 6

Comment: In 1.8 use `document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(pageNumber)`.

Comment: Hello @Keisuke246 were you able to make any progress? Btw in 1.8 the annotations example is named differently than in 2.0, "Annotation.java" and is in the example subproject of the source code download.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I've left this functionality out of my project for the moment as the bookmarks are working fine and the business it satisfied with it. I might try to do it later as we will upgrade to java 8 in the near future, but it's not on the table for now.